# BigQuery SQL Syntax do i need the project name and dataset? `projectName.dataSet.tableName.fieldName`

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm currently working through the Coursera Google Data Analytics Professional Certificate.
and I've run into some problems using the Join function. but this also led me to wonder why I have to write out the whole path of a field name whereas the tutor just references tableName.fieldName

this has been happening through the course and I've just come to accept it, but if there is a way to write my Query without including the projectname & dataset (like the tutor is doing) it will save me a lot of time.

all help is appreciated.

`projectName.dataSet.tableName.fieldName`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.  In general, one would use *table aliases* to qualify column references:

```
select ​t.fieldName
from `projectName.dataSet.tableName` t
-------------------------------------^ the table alias
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
employees.name AS employee_name,
employees.role AS employee_role,
departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
`applyingsql-325411.employee_data.employees` AS employees 
INNER JOIN 
`applyingsql-325411.employee_data.departments` AS departments
ON
departments.department_id = employees.department_id;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).